# MySQL partitioning by week automatically

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, partitioning, mysql-5.1

I created a table to log the activity of my application. This table will log more than 2 millions record per month. So I want to use partitioning by month or week

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `UL`.`Log` (
  `LogID` INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `LogDate` DATETIME NULL,
  `AssessorName` VARCHAR(255) NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`LogID`),
  INDEX `AssessorName` (`AssessorName`),
  INDEX `LogDate` (`LogDate`)
)
ENGINE = INNODB;
```

But the problem is I have to create the partitioning manually such as

```
PARTITION BY RANGE (EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM LogDate)) (
    PARTITION pre_2014 VALUES LESS THAN (201400),
    PARTITION jan_2014 VALUES LESS THAN (201401),
    PARTITION feb_2014 VALUES LESS THAN (201402),
....
```

Is the any way to create a partition by month or week automatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `YEAR_MONTH()`, it is not in the list here:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-limitations-functions.html

Instead, use `TO_DAYS(LogDate)` and explicit dates such as `'2014-01-01'`.

No, there is no "automatic" partitioning.  It is not too difficult a task to write Perl (or other language) code to fetch the partition structure from the `information_schema` and compute what partition to add next.

What do you hope to gain from `PARTITIONing`?  There are very few benefits.  I have listed them [in my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint).

Also, that link has code to deal with purging old partitions, plus how to efficiently use `REORGANIZE PARTITIONS` each week (or month).